# error message with rasberry pico w and micropython

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Im trying to connect my rasberry pi pico w to my wifi but i keep receive this message :

> the error [Errno 1] EPERM

This is my code :

```
import network
import socket
from time import sleep
import machine

ssid = '<myssid>'
mpd = '<mypassword>'


def connect():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, mpd)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'connected on {ip}')
     
try:
    connect()
    sleep(1)
    
except OSError as error :
    print(f' the error {error}')
    ##machine.reset()
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `EPERM` stands for "permission error".  You can use `sys.print_exception(error)` to get more info about where the error is happening (or just remove your code for catching exceptions), then edit your question to include the new info.